# Get parameters of a mocked method in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am using python's unittest.Mock framework.

I want to achieve following goal with mock:

The original method is like:

```
def mymethod(para1, para2, para3):
    return para1 + para2 + para3
```

I want to mock it to return the first para1 - discard the rest:

```
def mymethod(para1, para2, para3):
    return para1
```

I saw we can set return_value of a mocked object, but seems only a hardcoded one. I saw we can get the parameters of a mocked call, but only after that is called. - is there a way to get the parameter and return it dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`side_effect`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.side_effect) of the Mock Class:

```
import mock

def mymethod(para1, para2, para3):
    return para1 + para2 + para3

m = mock.Mock(side_effect=lambda *args: args[0])
with mock.patch('__main__.mymethod', m):
    assert mymethod(1, 2, 3) == 1
```

Comment: cool, that is what I am looking for, acutally, after reading you answer, I found it acutally listed in the docs: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/getting-started.html#side-effect-functions-and-iterables